# How do I convert a Blazor version 7 Server to version 8 InteractiveServer?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor version 6/7 Server app that I need to convert to version 8 InteractiveServer. I have the anti-forgery code in this which needs to change also.

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: FYI you can post a question and self-answer simultaneously. Also both parts must still meet the basic requirements for questions ([ask]) and answers ([answer]).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please provide specific guidance as to what is required to make this question better?

Comment: You should put the old code you have and that needs changing into the question, not the answer. you should also specify any additional details, like errors and similar you get when you try to use old code. This information can help others who have the same problem, but don't know that they need to convert anything.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for the suggestions. However, I think it flows better to say convert X to Y rather than I have X, now here's Y because it's mostly moving blocks of content. On the second part, anyone converting to the new render mode knows they need to convert and I think the title makes that clear. Again, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the contents of App.razor, remove the outer `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` and paste that as the contents of the newly created Routes.razor. Then change `AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly"` to `AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"`.

Old App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <div class="message--401">
                        <h1 role="alert">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h1>
                        <p>You must have an Admin claim and be set to use 2FA when logging in.</p>
                    </div>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="message--404">
                    <h1 role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</h1>
                </div>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

New Routes.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <div class="message--401">
                    <h1 role="alert">Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</h1>
                    <p>You must have an Admin claim and be set to use 2FA when logging in.</p>
                </div>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <div class="message--404">
                <h1 role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</h1>
            </div>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

In Program.cs, replace:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options => { options.DetailedErrors = debugMode; });
```

with:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents(options => { options.DetailedErrors = debugMode; });
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

and replace (after UseAuthentication(); UseAuthorization();):

```
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

with:

```
app.MapControllers();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

Finally, you copy _Host.cshtml to App.razor, and then delete _Host.cshtml. When doing this, delete the code around xsrf in App.razor.cs and _Host.cshtml - this is all now handled by the call `app.UseAntiforgery()`.

I am not going to list everything below because the few changes will got lost in the stuff that didn't change. So the below is what changed.Pay close attention to `<base>` as it's a subtle but critical change!

Change source in _Host.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <base href="~/" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" param-InitialState="initialTokenState" />
</body>
```

to the new (overwrite old content) App.razor:

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</body>
```